# api request returns json files and not html/xml browser content

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am sending get httpwebrequests to the facebook graph api and all was working fine till I deployed to production server and now module that expects html/xml response is not working and when tested url in internet explorer, the save file dialog pops up and the file needs to be saved. 
Other modules also send requests to the facebook graph but just differ in the form of requests so not sure what is going on here.

Any ideas appreciated

Edit:

Let me try and rephrase this. On my production server the httpwebrequest was not returning the correct result. So to Test it I copied the url http://graph.facebook.com/pepsi which is an example, should return the profile info viewable in the browser. The server has internet explorer v8 and I am not sure why it tries to download the file instead of displaying it in the browser. this is what is happening in my code and when I make a request to a different part of the api, then it works in my app but not in the browser

Answer (score 1):

Your question is not very clear. From what I gather, you want the display the JSON response in a browser. Instead, you are being asked to download a file by the browser.

Well, this is normal behaviour. The response you get from Facebook would most likely have a [MIME type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Type) of `application/json`. Most newer web browsers display the text in the browser itself. Some browsers, however don't know how to handle this content type and just ask you to download the file.

You mentioned that your module expects an html/xml response. Try changing this to application/json.

You also said that it works in your app but not in your browser. I don't know what you're making, but generally you wouldn't show raw json to the user in a browser, right?